# Pre launch reports devices

Tags: android, google-play-console

Does these devices provided by google for prelaunch test ??
those not match with my testers devices and my application is in internal testing. please some one help im new to google play console. [image: Devices]

I checked every thing im pretty sure those devices are from google but is there anything i dont know about this ?